# On the summation $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \left ( \frac{1}{n^3+n^2+n+1} \right )$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is a problem that I ran into. I seriously doubt if there is a closed form but you never know.

Evaluate the series

$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \left ( \frac 1 {n^3+n^2+n+1} \right) $$

I searched in vain to attack it using telescopic summation but I failed miserably. Then I remembered the following technique. Since ${\rm Im} \log (1+ix) = \arctan x$ we can express the sum as follows

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \left ( \frac{1}{n^3+n^2+n+1} \right ) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \left [ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n^2+1)} \right ] \\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Im} \left [ \log \left ( 1 + \frac{i}{(n+1)(n^2+1)} \right ) \right ] \\ 
 &= \operatorname{Im} \log \left [ \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left ( 1 + \frac{i}{(n+1)(n^2+1)} \right ) \right ] 
\end{align*}

I tried to combine it with the famous Euler product

$$ \frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{z^2}{n^2} \right) \tag{1} $$

but I see no connection. So, is there a possible way to evaluate it?

Comment: Possibly partial fractions plus the identity $\arctan a + \arctan b = \arctan \dfrac{a+b}{1-ab}$ will do it. $\qquad$

Comment: I guess we need some creativity to make what you suggest work ... !

Comment: Don't know if it can be useful
$$\arctan \frac{1}{n^3+n^2+n+1}=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{4 n^3 +4n^2+4n+1}\right)\right)+\\ +\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{4 n^3 +4n^2+4n+1}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Mathematica can find product,answer is enormus.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I am really interested in the answer ... !

Comment: @Raffaele Hmm... interesting ... can we use this to telescope the summation? Probably not!!

Comment: How about expressing the denominator inside the inverse tangent function as the sum of a finite geometric series?

Comment: @Messney How would that help ??

Comment: You don't know until you try.

Comment: Perhaps there's a generalization of the formula mentioned by Michael Hardy to a account for indefinitely many terms. Then the solution would just be plugging in $\frac{1}{n^3+n^2+n+1}$ for each term and taking the limit as n goes to infinity

Comment: The series seems to converge, believe it or not.

Answer (score 7):

We have
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1}\right) \\ = \Im\left(\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{i}{n^3+n^2+n+1}\right)\right)\right) \\ = \Im\left(\ln\left(\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^3+n^2+n+1+i}{n^3+n^2+n+1}\right)\right) \\ = \Im\left(\ln\left(\frac{\pi\operatorname{csch}(\pi)}{1+i}\prod_{k=1}^{3}\frac{1}{\Gamma(r_k)}\right)\right)$$
where $r_k$ is the $k$th root of $x^3-x^2+x-1-i$ (order doesn't matter since the product iterates over all of them). The last step comes from employing [equation 19 on here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html) (which comes directly from the Weierstrass factorization product formula for $\Gamma(x)$), and the fact that $\Gamma(i)\Gamma(-i) = \pi\operatorname{csch}(\pi)$.

Answer (score 5):

Something tells me this might be difficult to do by hand. Plugging in your product formula into Mathematica and then `Simplify`ing, this is what comes out:

[image]

Comment: The arguments of $\Gamma$ look like roots of some cubic...

Comment: Shock !!! Where did that come from ?

Comment: Designating the arguments of $\Gamma$ as $a, b, c$ in order of appearance, $a+b+c = 4$, $ab + bc + ca = 6$, and $abc = 4 + i$. This gives $x^3 - 4x^2 + 6x - (4+i)$ as a minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $x^6 - 8x^5 + 28x^4 - 56x^4 + 68 x^2 - 48x + 17$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. WolframAlpha gives $a$ as one root of the cubic and decimals matching $b$ and $c$ for the others, so this is plausible. Of course, where the polynomials came from is anyone's guess...

Comment: @ConnorHarris I'm guessing you meant $-56x^3$ there rather than $-56x^4$? :)

Comment: @numbermaniac I did, yes. Good catch